# Enable speaker during telephony call in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, call, iphone-privateapi, speaker

How can I enable speaker when call in progress, I am using this set of code, but this does not work

```
   let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
        try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.speaker)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch {
        print("AudioSession properties weren't set because of an error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

This set of code only changes the output port to speaker, but speaker is not enabled for telephony call.

I need to enable the speaker in the telephony call UI.
I do not mind use of private frameworks to achieve this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Any updates ?

Comment: try to make session active before override.

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: I dont know if there any reliable solution out there.